# Insert Array of values from Select query mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an application that shows the shift target of a certain reference. I have a lot of references divided in 3 shifts (morning, afternoon, evening)
The app is working good but now i want to reset the counter of the shift targets in the beginning of every shift for all references. I mean, when the clock is 6am, all the morning shift should put the counter on 0.
I have the following code but is not working. Something is missing and i'm stuck.

```
Dim rtime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, CInt(requestddate.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds))


        hora1 = New TimeSpan(6, 0, 0)
        hora2 = New TimeSpan(14, 0, 0)
        hora3 = New TimeSpan(22, 0, 0)

        ConnectDatabase()

        If rtime = hora1 Then

            count = 0

            Try

                With cmd4
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandText = "Select ShiftTarget.IDShiftTarget from ShiftTarget, turnos, linhas WHERE ShiftTarget.IDLinha = linhas.IDLinha and ShiftTarget.IDTurno = turnos.IDTurno And turnos.Descricao = 'Manha' And linhas.NomeLinha = '" & GlobalVariables.linha & "'"
                End With

                While objReader.Read()
                listaIDs.Add(objReader("IDShiftTarget").ToString())
            End While

            objReader.Close()

            DisconnectDatabase()

            ConnectDatabase()

            With cmd1
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "INSERT into contador (IDShiftTarget, Data, Contador) VALUES (@ID, @date, @cont)"
                For Each item As String In listaIDs
                    MsgBox(item)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", item)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cont", count)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
            End If
        End Try

        DisconnectDatabase()
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Update:
This is what i get (and it's expected) from the select query:
[image]

And this is the table where i want to reset the counter:
[image]

So, imagine, when the actual time is 6am, i want to insert something like:

```
IDContador   IDShiftTarget      Data      Contador
11933          32           2016-02-23       0
11934          19           2016-02-23       0
11935          20           2016-02-23       0
11936          35           2016-02-23       0
```

I cannot simply reset to 0 where idshifttarget is equal to 19,20,32,35 because that would reset all the records, and i want to keep them in the table.
I need to check the MAX(ID) where the shiftTarget is the value i got in the array, and then put the Contador to 0.

UPDATE:

I have made this changes in the code:

```
While objReader.Read()
                listaIDs.Add(objReader("IDShiftTarget").ToString())
            End While

            objReader.Close()

            DisconnectDatabase()

            ConnectDatabase()

            With cmd1
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "INSERT into contador (IDShiftTarget, Data, Contador) VALUES (@ID, @date, @cont)"
                For Each item As String In listaIDs
                    MsgBox(item)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", item)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cont", count)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
            End If
        End Try

        DisconnectDatabase()
```

With this code i can only see the first ID and in the console i get the next error:
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll

Comment: Please narrow down *I have the following code but is not working*. What is the expected behavior ? How does the code not meet this behavior? Which counter are you talking about? Do you want to set something in the database or in your code? I cannot see any link between your posted code and question, sorry.

Comment: Is your program running continuously/ as a service? If so you could create a `TimeSpan` which represents the remaining hours/minutes/seconds to the "next" 6am time shift. Additionally create a `Timer` whose `Interval` is set to the `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`. In the Timer Tick Event Handler execute your Inserts. After that set the Timer Interval to 24 hours. Proceed with the other shifts accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the program is running continuously and this code i posted is inside a 1sec timer. I don't think that adding more timers would be the best solution, once that the code i have is probably almost good. Is missing something but i can't see what. 
Anyway, thank you for your suggestion. I'll think about it :)

Comment: Another possibility would be planned sql tasks, like SQL Server-Agent Jobs, but I´m not familiar whith mysql in that topic.

Comment: If your code is already running in a timer - even better :) Just create 3 TimeSpan objects outside the tick handler, each representing the missing seconds to the next shift. Decrease these TimeSpan objects by 1 second in the tick handler. Check if one of them reaches zero -> Fire your inserts -> reset the TimeSpan.

Comment: I think i'm not expressing myself good. I know the theory to reset the counters. However, i'm having some problems with the code, because when i make the select query, i've got the array of values i want to reset. But when i try to do it in the Insert query, it's not doing anything. That's my real problem. Not the way to reset the counters.

Comment: Have you debuged your code? Is an exception thrown when calling ExecuteNonQuery? Edit: Your catch block swallows the exception if it has no InnerException. Change it so the original exception is also shown in the MsgBox. Edit2: You try to execute an Insert statement whil looping thru a DataReader which is not allowed in mysql.

Comment: So, i would need to make the inserts in separate?

Comment: Jap. Loop thru the DataReader and store all IDShiftTarget in a List or something. Then close the Reader, loop thru the List and execute the Inserts. I have to more concerns about your code: `If objReader.Read = True Then` will lead to that the first row of your query is ignored! 2nd: Both in your Select and Insert statements you concat parameters in the WHERE/VALUES clause. Please use [prepared statements with bound parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make some progress on this to put the program working as i expect.

Comment: Would be nice if you give a short note if it works. I could then post a well formatted answer ;)

Comment: I could save the IDs to a list properly (i can print them) but when i try to make the inserts, nothing is happening. I'll update my question with the new code. Check it please

Comment: Is Data in table contador of type Date or varchar? Also have you debuged the insert code?

Comment: Is Date type. And the Insert query is working good if i only execute it once, i mean, if i only reset the ID of the selected reference in the dropdownlist i have. But i want to reset all the references... Probably is better to continue this discussion on chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104380/discussion-between-vallete7-and-alex-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things in your code which lead to wrong havior:

- You cannot execute a CRUD action while looping thru a DataReader: 
  Create a list to store `IDShiftTargets`, close the DataReader and then loop thru the list and execute the Insert statements.
- Take care that the data types of your DB columns match with the code data
  types (IDShiftTarget int/Integer, IDShiftTarget date/DateTime, ...).
- When using a prepared statement with bound parameters make sure that you use
  `AddWithValue` only once outside the loop and set it in the loop with
  `Parameter("@ID").Value = item`
- Since the code is executed in a timer event which ticks every second, it is
  likely that a first execution has not finished until the next timer 
  ticks. If you want to run the code secure and synchron make sure that the
  current execution is not disturbed, e.g. setting `Timer.Enabled= False` at
  the beginning of the function and `Timer.Enabled=True` after function has
  finished. Or just set the timer tick high enough (*d'oh*).